# Cannot Pass Values from Bash Script to Java Program

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a java program from bash script.  I am providing the input values from script to the program.

**Java Code.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a = 0;
String str = "";
String str2 = " ";
System.out.println("hello");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//System.out.println(a);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
str = br.readLine();
str2 = br.readLine();
System.out.println(str + str2);

} catch(IOException ex) {
 System.out.println("exception: " + ex);
}

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  a = sc.nextInt();
 }

 }
}
```

**The bash script run.sh is**

```
#!/bin/sh

java test <<EOF
abc
def
5
6
EOF
```

**But the output of running the script ./run.sh is as follows:**

```
hello
abcdef
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at test.main(test.java:25)
```

*Can anyone help me in this regard.*

Comment: Basically, I am developing an online java compiler. So, its upto user, what code he has to write. So, the above code is the code given by the user which I have to compile and execute on the web server. Therefore, I cannot implement the suggested constraints to use only Scanner or BufferedReader. Can you help me in this regard. This was just a sample run by me on my machine. I am using PHP to execute java programs on server. Also, Can anyone help me how to pass the user input in realtime without passing before executing the program?

Comment: Please edit your last comments into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

You can't have a scanner and a reader both hooked up to the same stream like that.  They will steal each others input.

For your input, it looks safe to change

```
a = sc.nextInt();
```

to

```
a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different readers to simultaneously try to process the `System.in` stream, this will all but guarantee unpredictable and incorrect results - imagine if two different people tried to catch all the fish in a river; at least one will fail to do so.  In this particular case, the problem likely stems from using `BufferedReader`, which reads more than what you ask for in order to more quickly respond to future requests from the stream.

However the key is to pick one method for reading input and sticking with it.  In your case, I would suggest sticking to [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and leaving the `Reader` behavior out.  Consider the following:

```
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  str = sc.next();
  str2 = br.next();
  System.out.println(str + str2);

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    a = sc.nextInt();
  }
} catch(IOException ex) {
  System.out.println("exception: " + ex);
}
```

Notice a couple of things:

1. We use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure the `Scanner` closes the stream when it's done
2. We wrap all the stream-reading behavior in the try block, since potentially any part of it could fail
3. We use `Scanner.next()` to read a word from input, avoiding needing a `Reader`.

Pay attention also to `Scanner`'s `has*()` methods, which can be used to validate the next item in the stream exists and is the type you expect.  Your current code would still fail violently if anything but exactly the format you describe is passed in.  Using the `has*()` methods you can more elegantly error when unexpected input is passed in.

---

To be clear, this is neither a problem with `bash` nor `java` - they are behaving exactly as documented.  That it runs successfully on browxy.com (whatever that is) is mere coincidence, and in fact suggests that their implementation of `BufferedReader` is very poor.

Comment: Well... that's problematic.  You're basically saying you want broken code (i.e. using `Reader`s and `Scanner`s on the same stream) to "just work".  If the user gives your compiler code that is broken, what can you hope to provide back but broken bytecode?  [Garbage in, garbage out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the method signature of `main` to `main(String... args)` and pass them in over the command line like so?

```
java test abc def 5 6
```

Quick example:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) {

    for (String s : args) {
      System.out.println("String is: " + s);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The way I see it right now its about passing static parameters from a shell script into java <class>, if OP can elaborate about where the parameters come from maybe I'd have more useful advice.  I don't see how my solution is any different than reinventing the parameter wheel.